# Extract area with no noise

Tags: opencv, image-processing

1. What is the best way to extract the part with pattern from binary images like these? Size and position of pattern may vary a bit from image to image.

[image]
[image]

I've tried morphologyEx, but it looses too much info (and pattern position/size)

[image]

2. How do detect too noisy images?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

UPD
Looks like it works now. Still dont know how to detect 'bad' noisy frames. Here is an example with an excellent frame.

0. orig img (240x320).

[image]

1. (0)-> Morph close 4x4, to find large black areas.

[image]

2. (0) -> Morph open 2x2 -> Morph close 2x2 -> set black where black in (1).

[image]

3. (2) -> gaussian blur 13x13.

[image]

4. (3) -> gray to bin and leave only white zones with area more than some value.

[image]

5. When all the frames are processed 1-4:

```java
    for (var df in dFrames) {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
          if (df.frame[x][y] == 0xffffffff)
            screenImg[x][y] += (int)(pow(df.whiteArea, 1.2) / maxWhiteAreaInAllDfs * 100);
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        if (screenImg[x][y] > dFrames.length * 0.5 * (100/2).floor())
          screenImg[x][y] = 0xffffffff;
      }
```

[image]

6. Finally crop all the frames (4), wrap perspective, find pattern width/height and calc avg color in every 'square'.

[image]

Comment: what kind of morphology did you use?

Comment: It morph open with 3x3 kernel, but I've tried all the types.

Comment: May the pattern change from image to image or is it fixed (except for variations in size, position, inversion and noise)?

Comment: @simonet no, it doesnt change. The colors are inverted every 2-4 frames.